# 2 forms same view zf2 doctrine

Tags: forms, entity-framework, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have a project in ZF2 and Doctrine.
I have an Action that has 2 forms each with its own entity.
Already I can print both in my view.
But now I need to save these two forms one of each entity in the bank.
Just 1 submit button.
How can I do this?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you creat a fieldset for each entity. Each fieldset will contain all the fields and relationships for a specific entity.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.form.collections.html#creating-fieldsets

Answer (score 0):

sure serialize the two form and post to controller then
initialize 1st entity persist it . then initialize 2nd entity and persist it.

```
 $fristEntity = new fristEntity();
 //your set statement
 $em->persist($fristEntity);
 $em->flush();
 $secondEntity = new secondEntity();
 //your set statement
 $em->persist($secondEntity);
 $em->flush();
```

Comment: Yeah. My controller is that.. My problem is time for the view and how to submit only one to use this model. I will study the Fieldset.
Thank u.